# How does the density of states for black-body radiation change with geometry?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, geometry, density-of-states

If I have a hollow conducting cylinder with another conducting cylinder inside it (as with a coaxial cable), would the density of states of the photons/radiation between the two cylinders be any different to the case of just a cylinder by itself?

Likewise, if I have my coaxial cable and short it (ie. put it end to end)(but has a very small curvature) would the density of states be any different to the case of a close-ended hollow cylinder?

Answer (score 2):

Black-body radiation is caused by electronic degrees of freedom in the black body radiator. An ideal black body has eDoFs resonating at any frequency relevant to the temperature range that you consider. Your conductor certainly is far from an ideal black body at low temperatures but maybe quite close at high temperatures. For example Tungsten wires behave quite close to ideal black bodies at light bulb temperatures,
[image: Thermal spectrum of Tungsten wire]. 
What is the impact of the given geometry on the density of states? It will only affect wavelengths comparable to the dimensions of the geometry, so millimeters. Millimeter blackbody radiation is only dominant at Helium temperature. The spectrum peaks at about 1 micron for 3000K so it will peak at 1 mm for 3K, a temperature that can be reached in a liquid Helium cryostat.

Answer (score 0):

Blackbody radiation assumes thermal equlibrium with surroundings.

For example if you have a hollow sphere heated up with a small hole in it the radiation that comes out of the hole will have blackbody distribution of intensity vs wavelength / frequency

If you have a wire heated the spectrum would not look like blackbody radiation.

I am afraid that I do not follow the geometries you have described in your question, but I hope tht the examples I have given are useful.

Comment: How about the radiation inside the wire if it were hollow?

Comment: that should be black body at the temperature of the wire. - similar to the hollow sphere.

Comment: Would the density of states calculation for the radiation be the same as for a 3D box (if one were to try to calculate the internal energy)?